# How to show new points in arcgis online collector map?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-online, arcgis-collector

I have created Arcgis Online Collector Map. Is it possible to have new data points collected to stand out from the old ones? As of now, they all look the same and its hard to tell which ones are new and which ones are old/non existant.

Comment: I don't know the steps, but it sounds like you need to create a symbology based on a date field and anything before/after a particular date should be two different symbols.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could just use a data:time field to label the data.